# Disable button when there is a slash entered in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, button, textbox

How can I *disable* a `Button` in winform with c# when there is is `'/'` slash entered in the `TextBox` I have the following code in the event `TextChanged`

```
if (FirstnameTextBox.Text.Contains('/'))
    {
        SaveButton.Enabled = false;
    }
```

the `Button` stays `Enabled`. Can some one help?

Comment: try to put breakpoint and last '}'  and see what is the value of SaveButton.Enabled ?

Comment: Please, provide more code (e.g. entire `TextChanged` event - `private void FirstnameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}`)

Comment: Also change to `SaveButton.Enabled = !FirstnameTextBox.Text.Contains('/')` to re-enable the button..

Comment: @TaW there is a code but my questiion is more why the first code doesn't work

Comment: Maybe few lines after you set it to `true`?

Comment: We don't see the whole code. Instead of coming here with such a 'problem' you should ask your best friend, the debugger!!!

Comment: @pwn The posted code should work normally as expected. Something else you wrote in your application causes this unexpected behaviour. Set a breakpoint and check the value of `SaveButton.Enabled`.

Comment: @pwn Please post the whole code of the `TextChanged()` event. We might spot there something that leads to the unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use a double quotation instead of a single quote.

```
if (FirstnameTextBox.Text.Contains("/"))
            {
                SaveButton.Enabled = false;
            }
```